# Doing a group by and creating a hash with aggregated values

Tags: ruby

I have an array resulting of a SQL query:

```
Array = [
        ["a","ab",1,548], ["a","ab",2,215],
        ["b","ba",1,999], ["c","ca",1,784]
        ]
```

It's not possible to have twice the same value into the "third row" of subarray ***with the 2 first identical values / Read every lines of the post***.

`["a","ab",**1**,548], ["a","ab",**2**,215]` possible but

`["a","ab",**1**,548], ["a","ab",**1**,895]` not possible

It's from a SQL "group by" query on the 3 first values.

Expected result:

```
Array = [ ["a","ab", {1=>548, 2=>215} ], 
["b","ba", {1=>999} ], ["c","ca", {1=>784}] ]
```

I've tried with some combinations of `group_by` `map` but I didn't success.

```
Array.rows.group_by{|v| v}.map do |k|
  k[0] << {k[0][2]=>k[0][3]}
end
```

I get:

```
Array = [ ["a","ab", {1=>548} ], ["a","ab", {2=>215} ],
["b","ba", {1=>999} ], ["c","ca", {1=>784}] ]
```

`"a","ab"` aren't combined.

**EDIT:** I forgot, the 2 first values can be nil.  `[nil,nil,1,875]`

Comment: Your `Array` has three elements whose third value is `1`, and then you wrote that is not possible. How come? What do you mean?

Comment: Where ? "a","ab" is different to "c","ca" is different to "b","ba"

Comment: "Read every lines [sic] of the post." -- lol

Comment: regarding **edit 2** you stated earlier in the post that these results were not possible `[nil,nil,1,X]` would be in a single group according to your OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach, which groups the values on their "key" (i.e., first and second element), and additionally creates a hash of the 3rd element mapping to the 4th element. It seems that is what you want.

```
array = [
  ["a","ab",1,548], ["a","ab",2,215],
  ["b","ba",1,999], ["c","ca",1,784]
]

result = array.inject({}) { |h, sub|
  key, idx, val = sub[0..1], sub[2], sub[3]
  h.tap { (h[key] ||= {})[idx] = val }
}.map { |k,v| k << v }

# => [["a", "ab", {1=>548, 2=>215}], ["b", "ba", {1=>999}], ["c", "ca", {1=>784}]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = [["a","ab",1,548], ["a","ab",2,215],["b","ba",1,999], ["c","ca",1,784]]

a.group_by { |e| e.shift(2) }.map { |k, v| k << Hash[v] }
# => [["a", "ab", {1=>548, 2=>215}], ["b", "ba", {1=>999}], ["c", "ca", {1=>784}]]
```

The `group_by` creates groups by the first two keys, leaving the last two keys as values:

```
# => {["a", "ab"]=>[[1, 548], [2, 215]], ["b", "ba"]=>[[1, 999]], ["c", "ca"]=>[[1, 784]]}
```

This is already quite similar to what you need, you just need to switch the `Hash` to `Array`, and the `Array` to `Hash` - that is what the `map` does.

**Important Note:** this solution is *destructive*, which means `a` itself is changed when running this code (`shift` changes the actual arrays in the array.)

Comment: Clever use of `shift(2)` there. It's good that you noted it is destructive because that might have confused people using it.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know what solution choose. But I don't want at all to change the "a" array. ( I use it further on my code, but I can create a clone of "a" )

Comment: just because I like the look of this you can make it non-destructive although less clean with `a.group_by { |e| e.take(2) }.map{ |k, v| k << Hash[v.map{|e|e.drop(2)}] }` although `a.map(&:dup).group_by { |e| e.shift(2) }.map { |k, v| k << Hash[v] }` is cleaner and does not destroy `a`